# Python Pandas - Apply a filter to values in a table based on date

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I have the following code and output

```
df['revenue'] = pd.to_numeric(df['revenue']) #not exactly sure what this does
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], unit='s')
df['Year'] = df['Date'].dt.year
df['First Purchase Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['First Purchase Date'], unit='s')


df['number_existing_customers'] = df.groupby(df['Year'])[['Existing Customer']].sum()
df['number_new_customers'] = df.groupby(df['Year'])[['New Customer']].sum()

Table = df.groupby(df['Year'])[['New Customer', 'Existing Customer', 'revenue']].sum()

Table['TotalCusts'] = Table['New Customer'] + Table['Existing Customer']
Table['Repeat Rate'] = Table['Existing Customer']/Table['TotalCusts']
Table['NewCust Rate'] = Table['New Customer']/Table['TotalCusts']
print(Table)
```

Output

```
  New Customer  Existing Customer   revenue  TotalCusts  Repeat Rate  NewCust Rate
Year
2014          7.00               2.00 11,869.47        9.00         0.22          0.78
2015          1.00               3.00  9,853.93        4.00         0.75          0.25
2016          5.00               3.00  4,058.53        8.00         0.38          0.62
2017          9.00               3.00  8,056.37       12.00         0.25          0.75
2018         12.00               7.00 22,031.23       19.00         0.37          0.63
2019         16.00              10.00 97,142.42       26.00         0.38          0.62
```

Want to be able to apply a filter to the above table and be able to filter by data range.  So, if I filtered on "1/1/2019 to 3/1/2019" It would give me the number of new customers, existing customers and revenue for that period. How would I go about doing that?

Below are the columns of the original dataframe

```
>>> df.columns  
Index(['Subtotal', 'Region', 'Date', 'Ship To State', 'Ship To Customer Zip','Ship To Customer', 'revenue', 'ZipCleaned', 'Customer ID',
       'First Purchase Date', 'New Customer', 'Existing Customer',
       'Total Customers', 'Year', 'number_existing_customers',
       'number_new_customers'],
      dtype='object')
```

Comment: Kindly add the original dataframe `df` data, so it is easier for others answer.

Comment: Thanks. I've added those now into my question.

Comment: Change the table code to as shown below & keep the rest as it is.`Table = df.loc[df.Date.between('2019-01-01','2019-01-01')].groupby(df['Year'])[['New Customer', 'Existing Customer', 'revenue']].sum()`. You will have to give the dates matching the format you have in column `Date`

Comment: Thanks. That works but when I change "Date" in the attached to "First Purchase Date" which is a separate dataframe the filter doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Never mind. I've got it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arunmozhi's proposed answer worked as expected

```
#Table = df.groupby(df['Year'])[['New Customer', 'Existing Customer', 'revenue']].sum() # table with no date filters
#Table = df.loc[df.Date.between('2018-06-01','2018-06-30')].groupby(df['Year'])[['New Customer', 'Existing Customer', 'revenue']].sum() #with date filters for table
Table = df.loc[df.First_Purchase_Date.between('2018-01-01','2018-12-30')].groupby(df['Year'])[['New Customer', 'Existing Customer', 'revenue']].sum() #with date filter on first purchase date
```

Comment: Can’t you include the column selection in the `.loc[]`? Now that I think of it, you probably should.

Comment: where would i place the groupby?

Comment: Hmm good point, I must have gotten confused about which parts of the code were inside which brackets...